# What's the use of the new Star button in the project pages?

Tags: community-official-site

If you go to a Drupal project page (for example, [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)) you will see a new button with a Star, like this:

[image]

Logged-in users can Star and Unstar a project.

But what is the real use of this button?

I can't find all the users that have starred a project.

Comment: Hey downvoter. Why do you think that this question is bad? Help me to improve it please.

Comment: When I look at the views page, I don't see that "star" (as in your image), I only see the star itself, and the "35" ... That is when I'm not logged in. After I log in, I do get a similar Star-image like your question here. Also, do you mean "star" or "start"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this "Star"-facility as a way to "bookmark" specific contributed modules as your "favorites". Some more details about it (from [What’s new on Drupal.org? - April 2017)](https://www.drupal.org/drupalorg/blog/whats-new-on-drupalorg-april-2017):

> Users on Drupal.org may now [star their favorite projects](https://www.drupal.org/node/1973934) - making it easier to find favorite modules and themes for future projects, and giving maintainers a new dimension of feedback to judge their project's popularity. Users can find a list of the projects they've starred on the user profile. Over time we'll begin to factor the number of star's into a project's ranking in search results.

**Notes**:

- Projects that you star-ed are shown to others also. E.g [here are your current star-ed projects](https://www.drupal.org/user/1962106/starred).
- When I look at the views page (without being logged in to D.O), I don't see that "star" (as in your image), I only see the star itself, and the "35". After I log in, I do get a similar Star-image like your question here.

Answer (score 0):

For the moment the only thing that I can remark is a list with your starred projects, this is available in your profile:

[image]

And you can access trough https://www.drupal.org/user/YOUR_USERNAME/starred

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/drupalorg/blog/whats-new-on-drupalorg-april-2017 https://www.drupal.org/node/1973934